# Grunt.js build process very slow in network

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, less

my build process of grunt.js is very slow in the network. To compile LESS into CSS it takes about 180 seconds ... :-( This is not normal, right? 
Local everything is great and the build process takes less than 1 second. This is great!

My setup: 
- Windows 7 
- I use "Node.js command prompt" 
- Network server is a ReadyNAS Duo

What can I do? Network settings? Install plugin?

Greeting
Jan

Comment: what do you mean by "in the network"? Are your LESS files on a remote drive and compilation is done locally? or are you logging in to a remote machine and doing the compilation there?

Comment: We have a local company server where we store all our files and access it.

Comment: Hardware wise, it kind of sounds like your local computer might be faster than your server. I'm not sure, but I don't believe NAS' tend to be high end machines like a desktop.

Comment: I think the performance of the NAS is sufficient. I can also open large Photoshop files very quickly.

Comment: Here is a log of the task:
`Running "watch" task
Waiting...
>> File "less\custom\theme.less" changed.
Running "less:style" <less> task
File ./less/master.css created: 0 B -> 151.5 kB
Completed in 94.850s at Wed Oct 01 2014 09:31:31 GMT+0200 (Mitteleuropäische Sommerzeit) - Waiting...`